# Is there an intermediary that allows me to pay eBay purchases with Bitcoin?

Tags: payment, payment-processors

I mostly buy stuff on Ebay since Amazon and Bestbuy don't offer worldwide shipping, I live in southern Asia.

I have an account with my local public bank denominated in US Dollar to make my payments to Ebay. However, it is very hard to get USD in this country as rich people have all of it. If I used a local currency account instead, the bank would charge a 10% commission for each international payment for currency exchange and cross border fee.

Is there a Bitcoin solution for this?

Comment: Could you make your title a little more specific to your question?  Questions with titles like "Can Bitcoin Do This?" aren't very useful for understanding the topic of the question.  Your title should include what "this" is.

Comment: @Abraham-H: Please do not edit questions to reply to answers. Rather write an answer, which can be transformed to a comment, or better yet, ask a new questions and link it to this one for context.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is order an prepaid debit card with one of the various providers. They usually allow you to create virtual cards instantly, which are just denominated in one of the major currencies. One example is crypotopay.me

Comment: Abraham-H tried to ask the following as an edit: "@MICHAEL183 I dont think currently Ebay accepts bitcoin; could u explain me how Ebay will accept this virtual debit card u mentioned [@michael183]."